# header + sticky footer + content div that covers the rest, how to center content?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am using this code. http://jsbin.com/ibecak/1/. I took it from here: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html. This works well.

However I want to center the content div (magenta) in the space between header and footer in the container div (yellow).

How would I go around doing that without breaking anything? I have tried setting display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle on #content, but to no avail.

The important thing for me is that the footer gets pushed down when the window is too small, instead of overlapping everything, but I still want to be able to center #content in the remaining space of #container.

If at all possible, I'd like to know how to do this with only CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an easy thing to do. As the height value tends to work a little funny in browsers if it was width then there would be no problem.

You will need to use more than just 3 divs.

You will need to put your content div inside another div and use jquery to work out the height of the space between the header and footer. if the header and footer is a fixed height it will make it easier to work out.

Once you work out your height then you will need to absolute position your div inside the container div so that it sits within the middle of the space.

Answer (score 0):

> Question - I want to center the content div (magenta) in the space between header and footer in the container div (yellow).

The difficulty with trying to center the content div vertically is not knowing the height.  If it was a fixed height then you could do this.

**Example**

```
div#content{
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px; 
    // Negative margin is half the height of content div
    // To ensure it is in the middle
}
```

You could calculate the height with jQuery and then set the css styles.